# Warning: date_timezone_set() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in format_date()

Tags: drupal-7

I installed date module in drupal 7.
However when I tried using contextual filters as date.
I always got this error.

Warning: date_timezone_set() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in format_date() (line 1909 of httpdocs/includes/common.inc).
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in format_date() (line 1919 of includes/common.inc).

Does anybody encountered the same thing?

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue now. After commenting out **format_date()** function calls, the warning disappeared. I'll post back when I know more..

EDIT:
Found the source to this issue - the warning gets fired when you supply **invalid argument** to the **format_date()** function (I suggest you to check your variable values, mine was empty).

Comment: hi do u mean I have to do "php validate code" for the arguments?, but since my argument is date node filter by right it should not giving the errors. If date is invalid it would just return no results. I'm still encountering the issue whenever I input invalid dates...

Comment: No, I meant that you're probably giving wrong argument type - check [format_date](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7) at doc. Check if the first argument is a UNIX timestamp (and not a string or NULL).